# How to manage nuget between 2 microservies

Tags: .net, nuget

I have 2 services written in .net.

let's say A and B

in service B there is a project that is being built into a NuGet package using Jenkins. whenever we push a new change to this project the NuGet package is increased by 1.

service A is using the NuGet package for some shared models.

the problem is that while developing I can make a lot of changes in service B, i.e. the NuGet package that I need to test in service A.
in order for service A to see the changes in service B, I need to push it into the branch so that a build will happen. however, this will update the NuGet version all the time.

is there a way to work around it?

I tried to delete the reference to the NuGet package in A, and manually reference the dll but there are too many dependencies in that NuGet that break the code

Comment: Generally, try to have packages as standalone solutions that can be developed independently of the services that consume them. I've found this makes things much easier in the long run

Comment: I answered to a similar question, maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027489/how-can-you-debug-with-locally-built-nuget-packages/69029644#69029644

Answer (score 0):

Adding local NuGet source should work. The whole process should follow this pattern:

1. Create local folder for storing packages locally.
2. Locate nuget.config for service A or create it. Usually it sits in solution folder but other [well-known](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) locations are possible as well as any custom location.
3. Add local folder to  section in nuget.config.
4. Build service B into the package and publish it to the local folder.
5. Upgrade the package to the newest version.

Since all these steps could be done with command-line tools (nuget.exe, dotnet, msbuild) they can be automated in some scripting language (Powershell for example) and it should be easy to plug them in any build automation tool if you have it.

Also there are tools to automate dependency management across many repositories. They're especially good for big software products where many different parts are built by many different teams and there are many shared libraries between different parts. I guess from the question you have much simpler situation and such tool is overkill for you..