# Managing organization's internal .Net dependencies

Tags: .net, nuget, dependency-management

Our organization has many solutions (30+), each containing many projects.

We have situations where we have `Class Library "C"` in `Solution "C"` that is needed by `Class Library "B"` in `Solution "B"` which is in-turn needed in `App "A"` in `Solution "A"`.

**We're looking for better ways to manage this as it is currently very time consuming.**

What we currently do to manage these cross-solution dependencies is create NuGet packages, in this case starting with `Class Library "C"` and publish them to our private NuGet feed via Azure DevOps. This is all done by an automated pipeline upon pushing changes to our source control.

Once a NuGet package is created and has been pushed to our private NuGet feed, we move to the next solution up the line (`Class Library "B"`) and update the NuGet reference to reference the newly built package (`Class Library "C"`).

We repeat this process again in `App "A"`.

This has worked for a while, but over time it has worn on us because it is time consuming.

A change to `Class Library "C"` requires a commit, a pipeline build and publishing the new packages (*thankfully all automated*) before we can even begin working on `Class Library "B"` and then finally `App "A"`.

To add complexity to this, this is all assuming that we didn't introduce any bugs during our original changes to the deeply nested dependency `Class Library "C"`. If we did, we have to repeat this entire process from the start again once we find the bug and fix it.

Also, builds sometimes take up to 4-5 minutes to complete all the necessary steps. During this time we move on to some other task. This creates a lot of mental "context switching" You also don't return to the original task at hand *right* when the build is finishes because it's unreasonable to stop what you're doing at the exact moment it finishes, thus it is easy for iterations like I just mentioned to eat half of your day for something that should be trivial while never really being focused on any one thing as well as you could be.

I'm looking for improved solutions to managing internal dependencies across solutions that will cut down on the time involved.

We are not married to NuGet (despite our large investment already)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you debug with locally built nuget packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027489/how-can-you-debug-with-locally-built-nuget-packages)

Comment: @omajid, not quite. I'm looking for something more battletested than 1 upvote. Git-submodules do work, but we're not using Git (unfortunately). An alternative to this that I just thought about is symlinks. That may work... I'll have to think more about this tomorrow.

Comment: We have huge multi-solution setup. We broke all code into layers. L1-L4. On top we have UI layers, Web API and other end points. All L1-4 solutions build output into one `lib` folder. And all projects take their references from this `lib`. End point layers output goes into their specific silos but they take references from `lib`. We never have any hustle. You take branch and build in in steps via script.

Comment: Although potentially unpalatable, a giant well organised mono-repo could legitimately be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Around managing NuGet versions that you're consuming, you can make your life somewhat easier by using a `Directory.Build.targets` for setting up shared imports and downstream library versions all in one place for the various projects within the same solution/repo so that they're all pinned to the same versions - giving you better control of the NuGet Dependency equivalent of *DLL-Hell*. This is a great reference: https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/solution-wide-nuget-package-version-handling-with-msbuild-15/

Also in case it's helpful, I use this script to import my shared projects (which are in a separate repo/sln) into the same solution based on relative paths... This lets us code and interactively debug the shared projects in the context of the main entry point repos. It's also really handy for rapid refactoring in the shared projects since renames apply to my consuming libraries at the same time. We don't commit the subsequently impacted .Sln / .CSProj files.

There's lots of room for improvement to meet your specific needs, but here's one we dump next to our solution called `Add-CommonAsFramework.ps1` :-)

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string] $CommonPath, # Relative path to the common libraries, set up a default if your team has a convention
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
    [string] $SolutionFile # Try setting the default up "$PSScriptRoot/MySolution.sln"
)

if (-not (Test-Path -Type Leaf $SolutionFile)) {
    throw "SolutionFile value does not exist, $SolutionFile is not found"
} else {
    $SolutionFile = (Get-Item $SolutionFile).FullName
}

$commonRoot = Get-Item $CommonPath
if (-not (Test-Path $commonRoot)) {
    throw "CommonPath value does not exist, $CommonPath is not found"
}

$commonProjects = @(Join-Path $commonRoot.FullName -ChildPath "src/**/*.csproj") # NOTE: Fix for your convention!
$solutionPath = Split-Path -Parent $SolutionFile

Function Get-PackageReferenceNames (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)]
    [string] $SolutionFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 2)]
    [string] $ProjectRelativePath
) {
    $solutionPath = Split-Path -Parent $SolutionFile
    $projectFullPath = Join-Path $solutionPath -ChildPath $ProjectRelativePath
    $packageReferencesRaw = dotnet list $projectFullPath package
    $packageReferencesRaw -match '^.*>' -replace '^ +> ','' `
        | ForEach-Object { $_.split(" ")[0] } `
        | Sort-Object -Unique
}

Function Update-PackageReferenceWithProjectReference (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)]
    [string] $SolutionFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 2)]
    [string] $ProjectRelativePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 3)]
    [string] $PackageReferenceName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 3)]
    [string] $ReplaceProjectReferencePath
) {
    $solutionPath = Split-Path -Parent $SolutionFile
    $projectFullPath = Join-Path $SolutionPath -ChildPath $ProjectRelativePath
    dotnet add $projectFullPath reference $ReplaceProjectReferencePath
    dotnet remove $projectFullPath package $PackageReferenceName
}

Function Get-ProjectsInSolution (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)]
    [string] $SolutionFile
) {
    # Outputs as a string list, with the first two lines as headers
    $projectsListing = & dotnet sln $SolutionFile list
    $projectsListing | Select-Object -Skip 2
}

Function Get-RelativePathTo (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)]
    [string] $relativeTo,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 2)]
    [string] $path
) {
    if (!(Test-Path $relativeTo)) {
        throw "Invalid path $relativeTo"
    }

    try {
        Push-Location $relativeTo
        return Get-Item $path | Resolve-Path -Relative
    } finally {
        Pop-Location
    }
}

$tmp = Get-Location
try {
    Set-Location $solutionPath
    
    $projects = Get-ProjectsInSolution $SolutionFile

    # Test and add Common project to "framework" folder in solution if not already there
    $commonProjects `
    | Get-Item `
    | Where-Object {
        $commonProjectRelativeToSolutionPath = Get-RelativePathTo $solutionPath $_.FullName
        $projects -notcontains $commonProjectRelativeToSolutionPath
    } `
    | ForEach-Object {
        $commonProjectRelativeToSolutionPath = Get-RelativePathTo $solutionPath $_.FullName
        dotnet sln $SolutionFile add --solution-folder "framework" $commonProjectRelativeToSolutionPath 
    }

    $commonProjectNames = @{}
    $commonProjects `
    | Get-Item `
    | ForEach-Object {
        $commonProjectRelativeToSolutionPath = Get-RelativePathTo $solutionPath $_.FullName
        $commonProjectNames.Add($_.Basename, $commonProjectRelativeToSolutionPath) 
    }

    # Replace any project that references them via NuGet to use the project reference instead
    $commonRootRelativeToSolutionPath = Get-RelativePathTo $solutionPath $commonRoot.FullName
    $projects `
    | Where-Object {
        Test-Path (Join-Path $solutionPath $_)
    } `
    | Where-Object {
        # Is not already a Common project
        -not $_.StartsWith($commonRootRelativeToSolutionPath)
    } `
    | ForEach-Object {
        $project = $_
        $packageReferences = Get-PackageReferenceNames $SolutionFile -ProjectRelativePath $project
        $commonPackageReferences = $packageReferences | Where-Object { $commonProjectNames.ContainsKey($_) }
        $commonPackageReferences | ForEach-Object {
            $commonProjectRelativePath = $commonProjectNames[$_]
            Update-PackageReferenceWithProjectReference $SolutionFile -ProjectRelativePath $project -PackageReferenceName $_ -ReplaceProjectReferencePath $commonProjectRelativePath
        }
    }
} finally {
    Set-Location $tmp
}
```